# Terraform with azure CLI - error building account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

using the provider block

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  version         = "=1.44"
}
```

and after successfully logging in with

```
az login
```

running

```
terraform plan
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error building account: Error getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 2

on main.tf line 21, in provider "azurerm":
21: provider "azurerm" {
```

UPDATE:

If I change the provider block to:

```
provider "azurerm" {
 version = "~> 1.43"
}
```

and set the environment variables

```
ARM_USE_MSI=true
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=<...>
ARM_TENANT_ID=<...>
HTTP_PROXY=<...>
HTTPS_PROXY=<...>
http_proxy=<...>
https_proxy=<...>
```

than after executing terraform plan I get the following error:

**Connection to 169.254.169.254 failed. No route to host.**

which is very strange, as it seems to me, that a service endpoints IP is "hardcoded" into the terraform client.

Comment: outdated terrafrom\cli?

Comment: Terraform v0.12.20
+ provider.azurerm v1.44.0
+ provider.random v2.2.1

azure-cli (2.0.33)

Comment: Do you use the CLI inside the VM? How do you use login with CLI? VM identity or service principal?

Comment: @CharlesXu: In the meantime I found out, that removing ARM_USE_MSI=true solves my problem. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, you can add an answer to display the solution. I missed this variable.

Comment: For me another 'az login' helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing variable

> ARM_USE_MSI=true

Solved my problem.

This variable tells terraform to use Managed Service Identity. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). The problem was, that the Azure Instance Metadata service endpoint(available on the above mentioned IP), that is used from that point, is only accessible from within a VM, and I was running the terraform from my desktop.

Comment: Maybe you can show more things. For example, the reason why it solves your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I was already logged in via az cli, forcing another:

```
az login
```

Resolved this for me.

Comment: I had to run az logout first, but then this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
az login --tenant TENANT_ID
```

resolved by using tenant ID

Initially, I tried to log in with "az login" but got a similar error you posted.